# change object value v-for inside v-for in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, v-for

I am quite new in vue.
I have 2 array data like this :

```
listAccount : [
    {
        id_acc : a,
        amount : 1000
    },
    {
        id_acc : b,
        amount : 2000
    },
    {
        id_acc : c,
        amount : 1000
    }
]

listTransaction : [
    {
        id_acc : a,
        type : inc,
        amount : 100
    },
    {
        id_acc : b,
        type : inc,
        amount : 100
    },
    {
        id_acc : a,
        type : dec,
        amount : 100
    },
    {
        id_acc : a,
        type : dec,
        amount : 100
    }
]
```

and this is my component code

```
<div v-for="(list,index) in listAccount" :key="index">
    <div> {{list.id_acc}} -- {{list.amount}} </div>
    <div> transaction :</div>
    <div v-for="(each, index) in listTransaction" :key="index">
        <div v-if="each.id_acc == list.id_acc">
            <div> {{list.type == inc ? list.amount + each.amount : list.amount - each.amount}} </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i got result like this

```
my result:
a -- 1000
transaction:
    1100
    900
    900

b -- 2000
transaction:
    2100

c -- 1000
transaction:
```

but i want my result if the transaction type "inc", the transaction amount increase the amount of my account and if transaction type "dec", the transaction amount decrease the amount of my account if the transaction have same id_acc. my expected result like this:

```
expected result :

a -- 1000
transaction:
    1100
    1000
    900

b -- 2000
transaction:
    2100

c -- 1000
transaction:
```

i don't know how to change parent element value. can someone help me?

Comment: dont do on the dom/view make a [computed prop](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) which does everything you want, then simply output it

Comment: how to do that with v-for? because i need to looping my listAccount first then change the value with my listTransaction loop. im pretty new using vue.js and the documentation only showing if i have 1 array. @LawrenceCherone

Comment: whats inc and dec? are they strings or some variable?

Comment: its string, if the type inc its mean increase the value, if dec its means decrease the value @LawrenceCherone

Comment: np, I got it after looking more closely, have answered hope it helps.

Comment: thanks a lot @LawrenceCherone, i got the point

Comment: np, thanks for accept. sidenote if you can do the calculating serverside is better else its just offloading it to the user which depending on the number of transactions etc might be less efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, make a computed prop with all that you need then simply output it in the view, rather than calculating things on the fly inside the view.

Slightly diff to your expected output but with more details so you get the idea.

```js
//
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    listAccount: [{
        id_acc: 'a',
        amount: 1000
      },
      {
        id_acc: 'b',
        amount: 2000
      },
      {
        id_acc: 'c',
        amount: 1000
      }
    ],
    listTransaction: [{
        id_acc: 'a',
        type: 'inc',
        amount: 100
      },
      {
        id_acc: 'b',
        type: 'inc',
        amount: 100
      },
      {
        id_acc: 'a',
        type: 'dec',
        amount: 100
      },
      {
        id_acc: 'a',
        type: 'dec',
        amount: 100
      }
    ]
  }),
  computed: {
    accountTransactions: function() {
      for (let account of this.listAccount) {
        account.startingBalance = account.amount
        account.transactions = this.listTransaction.filter(i => i.id_acc === account.id_acc)
        account.transactions.map(i => {
          i.beforeBalance = account.amount
          account.amount = i.type === 'inc' ? (account.amount + i.amount) : (account.amount - i.amount)
          i.afterBalance = account.amount
        })
      }
      return this.listAccount
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.transactions {
  margin-bottom: 20px
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(account, index) in accountTransactions" :key="index" class="transactions">
    <div>
      {{ account.id_acc }} -- Starting Balance: {{ account.startingBalance }} End Balance: {{ account.amount }}
    </div>
    <div> transactions :</div>
    <div v-for="(transaction, index) in account.transactions" :key="index">
      {{ transaction.beforeBalance }}: {{ transaction.type }} {{ transaction.amount }} = {{ transaction.afterBalance }}
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <strong>Structure of computed prop</strong>
  <pre>{{ accountTransactions }}</pre>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.14/vue.min.js"></script>
```